# react state is one state behind button clicks

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a simple react page that renders 2 different html tables based off of which button is clicked on the screen. The issue I am having is that the table that is rendered for each button click is associated with the previous button click. (E.G. if I click button 1 one time then click button 2 the table associated with button 1 will be displayed.)

I am new to react so in order to get the tables to update I refactored my code to hold as much of the state as possible in the App.js class, I created the toggleState callback to associate the button clicks with state change of the parent, and I then pass that to DataProvider via the endpoint property. I realize this is probably where the state / UI disconnect is occurring, but I'm uncertain of the cause since I'm adhering to react principles to the best of my capability.

my class structure is as follows:

```
        App
    /        \
   /          \
  /            \
DataProvider   ButtonToggle
|
Table
```

If it is relevant the table class is building the table based off of an API call, I will add the code for this, but it is not causing me problems so I do not believe it to be the source of the issue.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table";
import ButtonToggle from "./ButtonToggle";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input : 'employees',
      endpoint : "api/employees/"
    };
    console.log("constructor app: " + this.state.input + "\n" + this.state.endpoint);
  }


  toggleState(input) {
    if(input == "employees") {
      this.setState({input : input, endpoint: "api/employees/"});
    }
    else {
      this.setState({input : input, endpoint: "api/categories/"});
    }
    console.log("toggleState " + this.state.input + "\n" + this.state.endpoint);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12 grid-margin">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-title">
            <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-3"></div>
              <div className="col-6">
                <h1> Striped Table</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="col-3"></div>
            </div>
              <ButtonToggle toggleInput={ (input) => this.toggleState(input)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-title"></div>
              <div className="card-body">
              <DataProvider endpoint={this.state.endpoint}
                        render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

DataProvider.js

```
class DataProvider extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        loaded: false,
        placeholder: "Loading..."
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    console.log("dataprov: " + this.props.endpoint);
    this.componentDidMount();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     fetch(this.props.endpoint)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
        return this.setState({ placeholder: "Something went wrong" });
        }
      return response.json();
      })
       .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, loaded, placeholder } = this.state;
    return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <p>{placeholder}</p>;
  }
}
export default DataProvider;
```

ButtonToggle.js

```
class ButtonToggle extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div className="col-3 center-in-div">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-fw" onClick={this.props.toggleInput.bind(this, 'categories')}> Categories </button>
      </div>

        <div className="col-3 center-in-div">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-fw" onClick={this.props.toggleInput.bind(this, 'employees')}>
           Employees
         </button>
         </div>

          <div className="col-6"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
export default ButtonToggle;
```

Table.js : I don't think this is a problem, but I may stand corrected.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import key from "weak-key";

const Table = ({ data }) =>
    !data.length ? (
    <p>Nothing to show. Records: {data.length} </p>
            ) : (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <h2 className="subtitle">
    Showing <strong>{data.length} items</strong>
      </h2>
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
    {Object.entries(data[0]).map(el => <th key={key(el)}>{el[0]}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    {data.map(el => (
             <tr key={el.id}>
                 {Object.entries(el).map(el => <td key={key(el)}>{el[1]}</td>)}
            </tr>
             ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
             );
Table.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
export default Table;
```

Comment: First step would be to stop binding the function to the ButtonToggle - since you're accessing `this` inside the function, you want it to be bound to the parent. You can bind it to the parent easily by declaring it as an arrow function, `toggleState = input => {`, then call it from inside ButtonToggle with `onClick={() => this.props.inputToggle("categories")}` etc

Answer (score 0):

Below is the minimum working code I could come up with. Your Button and Table components can be dumb components which will get data from parent component and will present it.
Your Parent or container component will have logic to set the properties for Button and Table component. 
As Table and Button components are dumb you can go with functional components.

I have added the code for calling api (I have tried to mimic the api call) and getting data in same parent component, you can separate it out.
You can work on style and validations as per your needs. 
Let me know if you need any further help.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "Category"
    }
    this.onBtnClick = this.onBtnClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(this.state.name)
  }
  getData(name) {
    if (name === "Category") {
      this.apiCall("/Category").then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data })
      })
    } else {
      this.apiCall("/Employee").then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data })
      })
    }
  }

  apiCall(url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (url === "/Employee") {
          res([{ "Emp Name": "AAA", "Emp Age": "20" }, { "Emp Name": "BBB", "Emp Age": "40" }])
        } else {
          res([{ "Cat Id": "XXX", "Cat Name": "YYY" }, { "Cat Id": "MMM", "Cat Name": "NNN" }])
        }
      }, 1000)
    });

  }

  onBtnClick(name) {
    let newName = "Category"
    if (name === newName) {
      newName = "Employee"
    }

    this.setState({ name: newName, data: [] }, () => {
      this.getData(newName);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (<>
      <ButtonComponent name={this.state.name} onBtnClick={this.onBtnClick}></ButtonComponent>
      <TableComponent data={this.state.data} />
    </>)
  }
}
const ButtonComponent = ({ name, onBtnClick }) => {
  return <Button onClick={() => { onBtnClick(name) }}>{name}</Button>
}


const TableComponent = ({ data }) => {
  function getTable(data) {
    return < table >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {getHeading(data)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {getRows(data)}
      </tbody>
    </table >
  }
  function getHeading(data) {
    return Object.entries(data[0]).map((key) => {
      return <th key={key}>{key[0]}</th>
    });
  }
  function getRows(data) {
    return data.map((row, index) => {
      return <tr key={"tr" + index}>
        {Object.entries(data[0]).map((key, index) => {
          console.log(row[key[0]]);
          return <td key={"td" + index}>{row[key[0]]}</td>
        })}
      </tr>
    })
  }
  return (
    data && data.length > 0 ?
      getTable(data)
      : <div>Loading....</div>
  )
}
```